# Is it possible to run Crashlytics while in debug mode?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am setting up Crashlytics in my app. It works fine when I build and run the release type. However, whenever I build and run the debug type, Crashlytics always crashes. Where am I going wrong?

I've tried updating Crashlytics (and all Firebase libs) to the latest versions. No change.

Application.java

```
        Crashlytics crashlytics = new Crashlytics.Builder()
                .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().build())
                .build();

        Fabric.with(this, crashlytics, new CrashlyticsNdk());
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false"/>
```

I'm expecting for Crashlytics to be working in debug build.

However this is the error statement I get:

```
E/CrashlyticsCore: The Crashlytics build ID is missing.This occurs when 
Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration.
Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
```

Comment: I guess you have just integrated Crashlytic SDK but haven't setup Crashlytic account from firebase console. So setup firebase creashytic from console, there you will get on google-service.json file. Download and add it into app/ folder and sync your project. And in manifest, change value of this "firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" to "true" to enable loggin of crashes.

Comment: @Vivek Are you still running into this issue?

Comment: @KevinKokomani I haven't attempted this since. I worked around by testing my app as a release build